# how to write code to split the data in to multiple workbook based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

VBA/Macro button to split the data in to multiple workbook based on column value

Need VBA or Macro button to select the file and split the data in to multiple file based on column value.

I do have an Macro file with the code where when I paste my data in to Raw data sheet and click on the button it will ask to select the headers on the file and again I need to enter the column header where I need to split the data based on that column and data is getting segregated on the same file.

So I need the Macro or VBA button based on below given requirements. Kindly help me on this.

When I click on the macro button, pop up should open to select the report from my local drive(the report will be in .xls or .xlsx or .csv format)
- Once I selected the report it should ask for the column header name to input.
- Once I input the column header name, the data needs to split in to multiple work books based on the unique cell value on the selected column.
- before saving the file the comma "," should be replaced with semicolon";" in any of the cell on the given workbook.
- the splitted work book should be named as "cell value - macro work book name". and file should be save in .csv format

-----for example: macro work book name is "Book1" and I do have the cell value like "ABC", "BCA", "DAB". so when I split the data to multiple workbooks it should name as below.

ABC - Book1
BCA - Book1
DAB - Book1

Please let me know if you need any further details

Currently it is not splitting in to multiple work book.

`````
````
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lr As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim vcol, i As Integer
Dim icol As Long
Dim myarr As Variant
Dim title As String
Dim titlerow As Integer
Dim xTRg As Range
Dim xVRg As Range
Dim xWSTRg As Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set xTRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the header rows:", "Raw Data", "", Type:=8)
If TypeName(xTRg) = "Nothing" Then Exit Sub
Set xVRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the column you want to split data based on:", "Raw Data", "", Type:=8)
If TypeName(xVRg) = "Nothing" Then Exit Sub
vcol = xVRg.Column
Set ws = xTRg.Worksheet
lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
title = xTRg.AddressLocal
titlerow = xTRg.Cells(1).Row
icol = ws.Columns.Count
ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('xTRgWs_Sheet!A1')") Then
Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "xTRgWs_Sheet"
Else
Sheets("xTRgWs_Sheet").Delete
Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "xTRgWs_Sheet"
End If
Set xWSTRg = Sheets("xTRgWs_Sheet")
xTRg.Copy
xWSTRg.Paste Destination:=xWSTRg.Range("A1")
ws.Activate
For i = (titlerow + xTRg.Rows.Count) To lr
On Error Resume Next
If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
End If
Next
myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
ws.Columns(icol).Clear
For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
Else
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
End If
xWSTRg.Range(title).Copy
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Paste Destination:=Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1")
ws.Range("A" & (titlerow + xTRg.Rows.Count) & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A" & (titlerow + xTRg.Rows.Count))
Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
Next
xWSTRg.Delete
ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

````
`````

Comment: Please paste your existing code

Comment: @HarassedDad - I have updated the code, if you want I will send you the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

This any help?

```
Sub DistributeCells(Sourcews As Worksheet, colLetter As String, startrow As Long)
'Takes data from Sourcews and places each row into a sheet named as the contents of that row in the column identified by ColLetter
'beginning at startrow
Dim r As Range

Set r = Sourcews.Range(colLetter & startrow) 'start here
Do
    AddIfMissing (r) 'create sheet if needed
    r.EntireRow.Copy Sheets(r).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'copy row
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)
Loop Until r = ""
End Sub

Sub AddIfMissing(r As Range)
On Error GoTo nope
Dim sheetname As String
sheetname = r.Text

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(sheetname) 'won't error if sheet exists
Exit Sub
nope:
Set ws = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
ws.Name = sheetname
r.Parent.Range("a1").EntireRow.Copy ws.Range("a1") 'copy headers from source
End Sub
```

Comment: where I need to add the above given code, whether on the command button or on the active sheet.

Comment: Actually I need a Macro file with a command button and macro code should assign for that button, so it should work like below. ----Once I clicked the command button, pop up window should open to ask for source file from local drive - it should work whether it is in .csv/.xls/.xlsx format. ------Once the file is selected, the comma "," in the file should be replaced with semicolon ";" and again pop up should open to input the column header name to split the data. -----Once I input the column header the data needs to split in to multiple work book based on the column value.

Comment: the splitted work book should be named as "cell value - macro work book name". and file should be save in .csv format

Comment: Please help me on my request